# How do I delete data from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have facing problem to delete all data from multiple tables? Anyone can guide me how to delete data from multiple tables? I am using MySQL.

Scenario:

I want delete data in four table according the first table "transaction_main" column name "id"

- first table name is transaction_main and column name is id;
- Second table name is transaction_point and column name is id_transaction_main;
- third table name is total_earning and column name is id_transaction;
- fourth table name is transaction_credit and column name is id_transaction_main;

May I know using below method to delete data?

```
  DELETE t1,t2 

  FROM table1 AS t1 

  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ...

  INNER JOIN table3 t3 ...
```

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the tables has a relation you should configure the on delete cascade in the foreign key constraints...

the foreign key creation would be like

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T2
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2_Cascade
   FOREIGN KEY (fk_id) REFERENCES dbo.T1(pk_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```